# Inline SVG with use tag stopped working with recent browsers

Tags: html, svg, href, inline

I have this webpage on hold for about an year now that I decided to finally finish. To my surprise the code is now showing differently than before. I narrowed it down to using inline SVG with the `<use>` tag that simply stopped working with the latest browsers. I tried with latest version of Firefox (68.0.1) and Opera. Firefox is the main browser I was testing with, but plan on testing with others when I'm done (of course).

!!EDIT!! I was actually using an identifier to reference a symbol inside the svg file but it seems even without that it stopped working, so let's start by that (example follows...).

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en-US">
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    
    </head>
    <body>
     <div>
    
    TEST TEXT
    
     <svg>
      <use href="imgs.svg#tst"></use>
     </svg>
             
     </div>
    </body>
    </html>
    
    
    <!-- THE ACTUAL SVG FILE CALLED imgs.svg -->
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE svg>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
     <symbol id="tst" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
     <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4"  fill="yellow" />
    </symbol>         
   </svg>
```

Comment: A use element cannot point to a complete SVG file in any browser I know. It has to point to a fragment. w3c has proposed that this change but as far as I know no browsers  have made that change yet. So you example has never worked rather than stopped working in recent browsers.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I messed the example, it was working before. If you change the svg file to use a symbol with an id and a viewbox and then reference that id (i.e. <use href="imgs.svg#id></use>) it still doesn't work. It also doesn't work if you encapsulate the svg in a g element instead of a symbol, in which case it needs a viewbox in the <use> element. All this is inspired by this article:https://css-tricks.com/svg-symbol-good-choice-icons/

Comment: I suggest you edit your question an example that should work then.

Comment: how are you testing it? when run from a folder i get a security warning in the console, but when run from a server, your example (plus fragment identifier) work well...

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I've always been testing this from a folder with Firefox. Just edited the above code. That was working previously with Firefox when the svg is in a separate file. I don't know how to add the svg file as an external file in this site when running the code snippet (is that even possible ?), instead of embedded in the html, so when reading the above example imagine the svg is in an external file :) .. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're running this from a file system and not from a web-server. That's the problem.

This is due to the fixing of a security vulnerability recently [CVE-2015-7186](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2015-7186)

Running from a filesystem is now much more restricted, basically you can no longer reference one file from another. We're discussing what to do about this in [bug 1565509](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1565509), but as we currently match Safari I'm not sure whether we'll change to match Chrome or Chrome will change to match us.

In the meantime, use a web server or convert the referenced file to [a data uri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) and embed it in the parent document.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This sucks, it complicates testing basic pages a lot... By the way, it would be cool if the browser could warn the user that it's blocking something, I lost literally hours pulling my hair trying to figure it out...